# Stress-Energy tensor in different vacua from De Witt paper

Tags: quantum-field-theory, qft-in-curved-spacetime

The equations (175)-(176), describing the relation between the expectation value of the stress-energy tensor in $in$ or $out$ vacua and the one obtained by differentiation of the effective action, of the paper ["Quantum field theory in curved spacetime" of B. De Witt](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370157375900514) are said to have their second term finite. However, given that the coefficients $\Lambda_{ij}$ and $V_{ij}$ are given by (162), and that the coefficients $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not bounded, (neither the $T(u_i^*,u_j^*)$ term, defined in (12)), neither have I been able to prove a boundedness condition from the Bogoliubov relation that they must satisfy (see e.g. eq. 3.22 of [Krishnan's review](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.5875v1.pdf)), I don't see why those second terms would be finite...

I would gratefully appreciate any help.